# Distance between trunctated random walk and its normal form

Tags: pr.probability, limits-and-convergence

I have $$X_i \sim N(0,1), \quad S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n,$$
$$  \mathscr{S}_n (t, \omega) := \frac{1}{ \sqrt{n} } \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[ S_{i-1} (\omega ) + n \left( t - \frac{i-1}{n} \right) X_{i}(\omega) \right] \textbf{1}_{ \left( \frac{i-1}{n}, \frac{i}{n} \right] } (t) $$ and let $$d(f,g) := \sup_{x \in [0,1]}| f(x) - g(x) | .$$

Then $$ Y_i^{(v)} := X_i \textbf{1}_{\{ |X_i| \leq v \} }, 
        X_i^{(v)} := \left( Y_i^{(v)} - E [ Y_1^{(v)} ] \right) $$ analogically we define
$$ S_n^{(v)} = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \textbf{1}_{ \left\{ \left| X_i \right| \leq v \right\} } - E \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \textbf{1}_{ \left\{ \left| X_i \right| \leq v \right\} } \right] $$ and $\mathscr{S}_n^{(v)}$.
In the lemma 3.2 (lecture notes on Donsker's theorem Davar Khoshnevisan,p.6, [https://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/ps-pdf-files/donsker.pdf](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Edavar/ps-pdf-files/donsker.pdf)) it's shown that

$$ \sup_{n \geq 1}  \| d \left( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n \right) \|_2 \leq 2 \sqrt{E \left[ X_1^2; |X_1| > v \right] } \text{ for all } v>0.$$

But to prove the Donsker's theorem we also need that

$$ \lim_{v \to \infty} \sup_n P \left( d \left( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n \right) > \lambda \right)=0$$ for all $\lambda>0$ which should follow from the inequality above and  Chebyshev’s inequality. I don't know how to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
&\sup_{n\ge1}\sqrt{E[d\left( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n \right)^2]} \\ 
&=\sup_{n\ge1}\|d\left( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n \right) \|_2 \leq 2 \sqrt{E \left[ X_1^2; |X_1| > v \right] } \text{ for all } v>0. 
\end{aligned}
$$
So, by the Chebyshev/Markov inequality,
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
&\lim_{v \to \infty} \sup_n P \left( d \left( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n \right) > \lambda \right) \\ 
&\le\lim_{v \to \infty} \sup_n 
\frac{E[d\left( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n \right)^2]}{\lambda^2} \\ 
&\le\lim_{v \to \infty}  
\frac{4E \left[ X_1^2; |X_1| > v \right] } 
{\lambda^2} 
=0,
\end{aligned}
$$
because, by the dominated convergence theorem, $E \left[ X_1^2; |X_1| > v \right]\to0$ as $v\to\infty$.

Comment: There should be $\sup_{n\ge1}\sqrt{E[d\left( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n \right)^2]}$ right? But i have another stupid question. Why the $\sup_{n\ge1}\sqrt{E[d\left( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n \right)^2]} = \sup_{n\ge1}||{d\left( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n \right)}||_2$ ?

Comment: (i) The brackets are optional. By a standard convention, $EY^2:=E[Y^2]$. (ii) We have $\sup_{n\ge1}\sqrt{E[d\left( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n \right)^2]} 
=\sup_{n\ge1}\|d\left( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n \right) \|_2$ because, by definition, $\|d( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n ) \|_2=\sqrt{E[d( \mathscr{S}_n^{(v) }, \mathscr{S}_n )^2]}$ or, generally, $\|Y\|_2:=\sqrt{EY^2}$.

Comment: I'm so sory but i don't know one thing to understand entire proof. How doeas the the dominated convergence theorem is used here?

Comment: @nodis6 : Let $f_v(x):=x^2\,1(|x|>v)$ and let $\mu$ denote the probability distribution of $X_1$, so that $E[ X_1^2; |X_1| > v]=\int_{\mathbb R}f_v(x)\,\mu(dx)$ and $\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)\,\mu(dx)=E[X_1^2]<\infty$, where $g(x):=x^2$. We have $f\le g$ and $f_v(x)\to0$ for each real $x$ as $v\to\infty$. So, by the dominated convergence theorem, $E[ X_1^2; |X_1| > v]=\int_{\mathbb R}f_v(x)\,\mu(dx)\to0$ as $v\to\infty$.

Comment: Okay, I'll make a note of it. Thank you very, very much.

Comment: Yes, sorry it was my mistake i read inequality wrong. I'm deleting my last comment.